# named pipes between winform (C#) and python

Tags: c#, python, .net, ipc, named-pipes

I am working on a window form app (C#) that should kick an external process and display some results and/or error messages from the exe in the form app.
I cannot seem to be able to form a named pipe connection between the form app and external process (exe) made in python. The exe fires up and works fine but it does not seem to hold the named pipe connection. So, I am not able to get any messages as such from the exe.
The exe is made with pyinstaller and named pipe connection seems to work pretty fine when paired with a window console app i.e. I could get messages back from the exe to a console app.

**Consolse App**

The script below can get return messages from the exe on to console.

```
namespace pipeConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream("teropipe");
            Console.Write("Attempting to connect to the pipe...");
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"my\path\to\external\app\tempp.exe");
            pipeClient.Connect();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to the pipe");
            Console.WriteLine("There are currently {0} pipe server instances open.", pipeClient.NumberOfServerInstances);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(pipeClient);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pipeClient);
            string temp;
            while ((temp = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received from server: {0}", temp);
            }
            Console.Write("Press Enter to continue..");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

But when I tried a similar thing on window form app I am not able to get anything from the python server

**Form App**

Although I have used a similar approach for the form app somehow no messages are being returned. In fact, it looks like the named piped connection isn't being held open for the form to communicate.

```
namespace pipeDemoForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void okayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream("teropipe");
            //MessageBox.Show("attempting to connect");
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"my\path\to\external\app\tempp.exe");
            pipeClient.Connect();
            string numb = pipeClient.NumberOfServerInstances.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("There are currently {0} pipe server instances open", numb);
            if (pipeClient.IsConnected)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There are currently {0} pipe server instances open", pipeClient.NumberOfServerInstances.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Python Script** - tempp.exe

The following is the python script, which I have packaged into a onefile exe with pyinstaller.

```
import win32pipe
import win32file

def process():
    pipe_handle = win32pipe.CreateNamedPipe(r'\\.\pipe\teropipe',
                              win32pipe.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
                              win32pipe.PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | win32pipe.PIPE_WAIT,
                  1,65536,65536,300,None)
    win32pipe.ConnectNamedPipe(pipe_handle, None)
   # business logic
    ..................
    #write some output to the form app
   win32file.WriteFile(pipe_handle,"some string return from above")
```

Comment: You can always hook into the `StandardOutput` of the process.